# Why does zip password cracker show strange/invalid passwords

Tags: python-2.7, zip

This script tries to open the password-protected file arch.zip, using words from words.txt, which is a list of [476k English words](https://github.com/dwyl/english-words). The password is "passwordy" and I have added this twice to words.txt, once near the beginning and once as the final word of the file.

```
with open("words.txt", "r") as the_text:
    for entry in the_text.readlines():
        password = entry.strip('\n')
        try:
            with zipfile.ZipFile('arch.zip', 'r') as zf:
                zf.extractall(pwd=password)
                print '[+] Found password = ' + password + '\n' 
        except:
            pass
```

This tries every line, even when it has matched the password, and I know this sucks but it shows the problem - several non-password words get matched before the script ends with a final, correct match.

I have easily fixed this (with exit(0) in the try/except) but I am curious why the incorrect matches?

```
[+] Found password passwordy

[+] Found password flashtubes

[+] Found password hecatontarchy

[+] Found password Judette

[+] Found password kiss-me-quick

[+] Found password miriness

[+] Found password pre-earthly

[+] Found password tenositis

[+] Found password unconsolable

[+] Found password passwordy
```

Comment: Please don't include output as links to images, paste it in your post, too

Comment: Will do, thanks man